# Add id attribute to hyperlinks through PHP Regular Expressions

Tags: php, class, href, preg-match-all

I am still relatively new to Regular Expressions and feel My code is being too greedy. I am trying to add an id attribute to existing links in a piece of code. My functions is like so:

```
function addClassHref($str) {
//$str = stripslashes($str);
$preg = "/<[\s]*a[\s]*href=[\s]*[\"\']?([\w.-]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
preg_match_all($preg, $str, $match);
foreach ($match[1] as $key => $val) {
    $pattern[] = '/' . preg_quote($match[0][$key], '/') . '/';
    $replace[] = "<a id='buttonRed' href='$val'>{$match[2][$key]}</a>";
}
return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
}
```

This adds the id tag like I want but it breaks the hyperlink. For example:

If the original code is : `<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>`

Instead of `<a id="class" href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>`

It is giving
 `<a id="class" href="http">Link</a>`

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique. And you should use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead of matching first and then using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: You did not ask for it, and for output modification it's usually stupid, so a comment: This would be simpler without a regex, and e.g. QueryPath `htmlqp($html)->find("a") FOREACH attr("id", "buttonRed".($i++));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some overcomplications in your regex :)

Also, there's no need for the loop as **[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** will hit all the instances of the search pattern in the relevant string. The first regex below will take everything in the a tag and simply add the id attribute on at the end.

```
$str = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>' . "\n" .
'<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link</a>' . "\n" .
'<a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Link</a>';

$p = "{<\s*a\s*(href=[^>]*)>([^<]*)</a>}i";
$r = "<a $1 id=\"class\">$2</a>";

echo preg_replace($p, $r, $str);
```

If you only want to capture the *href* attribute you could do the following:

```
$p = '{<\s*a\s*href=["\']([^"\']*)["\'][^>]*>([^<]*)</a>}i';
$r = "<a href='$1' id='class'>$2</a>";
```

Comment: This does work, but will it not effect other tags. for example if target="_blank" is set. Will it still achieve the same results? These are user generated links and I want to ensure it isn't affected if target is set.

Comment: the regex takes *everything* in the a tag and simply adds the id="class" attribute. are you looking to *ONLY* capture the href attribute?

Comment: To clarify I want to leave the link ALONE but add the id attribute to be set to class on every link in the requested string.

Comment: you should use what works for you and what you're comfortable with -- DOM is more robust and often less processor-intensive than regexes ... but as Ralph Waldo Emerson would say, "a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds"

Answer (score 3):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML or HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$all_a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$firsta = $all_a->item(0);
$firsta->setAttribute('id', 'idvalue');
echo $doc->saveHTML($firsta);
```

Comment: +1 Though possibly not necessary for this particular task, DOM parsing is usually the best option for DOM modifications -- especially in place of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your first subpattern `([\w.-]*)` doesn't match `:`, thus it stops at "http".

Couldn't you just use a simple `str_replace()` for this? Regex seems like overkill if this is all you're doing.

```
$str = str_replace('<a ', '<a id="someID" ', $str);
```

Comment: Issue is that these are user generated links. If for example they set target="_blank" will it be left alone? I am relatively new to preg_match but I want to ensure that the script isnt being oversmart I guess and just replacing every exact match?

Comment: @wiseman7687 Yeah, in my above example, you're only affecting the `<a ` portion. Everything after that would be untouched.